How to pass properties between classes
I have PaginatedDataTable:
class PaginatedDataTableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginatedDataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  _PaginatedDataTableExampleState createState() =>
      _PaginatedDataTableExampleState();
}

class _PaginatedDataTableExampleState extends State<PaginatedDataTableExample> {
  int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
          onRowsPerPageChanged: (newRowsPerPage) {
            setState(() {
              _rowsPerPage = newRowsPerPage!;
            });
          },
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "id",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "Begin",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "End",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          source: DataTableSourceExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And DataTableSource for it:
class DataTableSourceExample extends DataTableSource{
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = List.generate(
    999999,
    (index) => {
      "id": index,
      "begin_datetime": DateTime.now(),
      "end_date": DateTime.now(),
    },
  );


  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["id"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["begin_datetime"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["end_date"].toString())),
    ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => data.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;

}

But I previously created a List for the test in the DataTableSourceExample. In the future, I plan to access a third-party API, which will have a million or more records; I don’t want to download them all at once. So I want to load only the data from the API that needs to be displayed on the page.
How to pass to DataTableSourceExample from PaginatedDataTableExample the number of rows on the page (if I understand correctly, this is rowsPerPage) and the index of the element from which the required number of rows should be loaded?
Sorry for my bad English.

pass the page length in DataTableSourceExample constructor

@pskink How? I don't understand.
